# How to declare constexpr extern?

Tags: c++, extern, constexpr

Is it possible to declare a variable `extern constexpr` and define it in another file?

I tried it but the compiler gives error:

> Declaration of `constexpr` variable '`i`' is not a definition

in .h:

```
extern constexpr int i;
```

in .cpp:

```
constexpr int i = 10;
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No, you can't do it. Here's what the standard says (section 7.1.5):

> 1  The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a
> variable or variable template, the declaration of a function or
> function template, or the declaration of a static data member of a
> literal type (3.9). If any declaration of a function, function
> template, or variable template has a constexpr specifier, then all its
> declarations shall contain the constexpr specifier. [Note: An explicit
> specialization can differ from the template declaration with respect
> to the constexpr specifier. Function parameters cannot be declared
> constexpr. — end note ]

Some examples given by the standard:

```
constexpr void square(int &x);  // OK: declaration
constexpr int bufsz = 1024;  // OK: definition
constexpr struct pixel {  // error: pixel is a type
    int x;
    int y;
    constexpr pixel(int);  // OK: declaration
};

extern constexpr int memsz; // error: not a definition
```

Answer (score 35):

**C++17 `inline` variables**

This awesome C++17 feature allow us to:

- conveniently use just a single memory address for each constant
- store it as a `constexpr`
- do it in a single line from one header

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>

#include "notmain.hpp"

int main() {
    // Both files see the same memory address.
    assert(&notmain_i == notmain_func());
    assert(notmain_i == 42);
}
```

notmain.hpp

```
#ifndef NOTMAIN_HPP
#define NOTMAIN_HPP

inline constexpr int notmain_i = 42;

const int* notmain_func();

#endif
```

notmain.cpp

```
#include "notmain.hpp"

const int* notmain_func() {
    return &notmain_i;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -c -o notmain.o -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic notmain.cpp
g++ -c -o main.o -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
g++ -o main -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.o notmain.o
./main
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/085c4b22b1b290a6d033a44958d05054e7e303c7/cpp/inline_variable).

The C++ standard guarantees that the addresses will be the same. [C++17 N4659 standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4659.pdf) 
10.1.6 "The inline specifier":

> 6 An inline function or variable with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units.

cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline explains that if `static` is not given, then it has external linkage.

See also: [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work)

Tested in GCC 7.4.0, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question though. you definitely define it in the header.

Comment: Helpful, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 7):

What you probably want is extern and constexpr initialization, e.g.:

```
// in header
extern const int g_n;

// in cpp
constexpr int g_n = 2;
```

This is support though in Visual Studio 2017 only through conformance mode:

- [/Zc:externConstexpr (Enable extern constexpr variables)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-externconstexpr?view=vs-2017)
- [constexpr definition of extern const variable](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/121763/constexpr-definition-of-extern-const-variable.html)

Comment: In my case this worked with `g++ -std=c++14`. But the linker *failed* when compiling with `g++ -std=c++17`!

Answer (score 4):

No. Extern constexpr does not make any sense. Please read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

i.e. the bit

> it must be immediately constructed or assigned a value.

Comment: Okay, "extern constexpr" doesn't make sense. Got it. But can you do a declaration of a constexpr variable? And if so how?

Not being able to declare a constexpr variable seems like a huge limitation so I hope that there is some way.

Comment: Actually, extern constexpr does make sense, and would be useful. In particular, static constexpr class member variables automatically have external linkage (which is a huge inconsistency and gotcha - people often forget to add a definition in a .cc file).

Fortunately C++17 fixes much of this with inline variables - "inline constexpr" will avoid many of the problems with constexpr globals in headers. Sadly many of us can't use C++17 yet.

Comment: @SethML awesome! I've added a full example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208685/how-to-declare-constexpr-extern/53896773#53896773

Comment: Hmm... I would say `extern constexpr` makes sense in situations where a compile-time constant may potentially be ODR-used, as a way to tell the compiler that there actually _is_ only a single definition, instead of the usual "if a constant's not ODR-used, act _as if_ there's only a single definition."  Not all that common, but you never know when you might need it for something.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, you just need to replace `constexpr` with `const` in the header:

```cpp
// declaration, possibly in header
extern const int i;

// source file
constexpr int i = 0;
```

The basic idea behind `constexpr` for objects is:

- make it `const`
- initialize it with a constant expression

The former part can be done by using `const` in the header, latter part is only relevant to the initialization in the source file.

### Is this really allowed?!

Yes. Let's look at the relevant sections in the standard:

> Two declarations of entities declare the same entity if, [...], **they correspond**, have the same target scope that is not a function or template parameter scope, and either
>
> - they appear in the same translation unit, or [...]
> - **they both declare names with external linkage.**

- [[basic.link] §8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#8)

In plain terms, both `i` have the same name so they correspond, and they both have external linkage due to `extern`.

> For any two declarations of an entity `E`:
>
> - If one declares `E` to be a variable or function, the other shall declare `E` as one of the same type.
> - [...]

- [[basic.link] §11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#11)

That begs the question: are two variables the same type if one is `constexpr` and the other is `const`?

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. [...]

- [[dcl.constexpr] §6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6)

The answer is yes, it just makes our object `const`, it doesn't change the type in any other way. The only remaining question is whether we are allowed to put `constexpr` on one declaration but not on another:

> If any declaration of a **function or function template** has a `constexpr` or `consteval` specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the same specifier.

- [[dcl.constexpr] §1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1)

No, there are only restrictions for functions, not for variables. It is allowed to make one declaration `const` and the other `constexpr`.

### It is allowed, but isn't it totally useless?

Not entirely. One possible use-case is if you have a large `constexpr` lookup table that you want to compute at compile time, but don't want to put this initialization into a header, in order to reduce compile times.
If it's really important to compute this table at compile time, but not so important to have a definition of its contents visible everywhere (for inlining and optimizations), `extern constexpr` can help.

- `inline constexpr` would require an identical definition (and initialization) everywhere to not violate the one definition rule. As a result, we incur the cost in every translation unit that includes our header.
- `static constexpr` is even worse, because every translation unit has its own copy of this large lookup table.
- `extern constexpr` covers this use-case perfectly.

---

*Note: not all compilers conform to the standard by default. Use [`/Zc:externConstexpr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-externconstexpr?view=msvc-170) when compiling with MSVC.*

Answer (score 2):

I agree with 'swang' above, but there is a consequence. Consider:

ExternHeader.hpp

```
extern int e; // Must be extern and defined in .cpp otherwise it is a duplicate symbol.
```

ExternHeader.cpp

```
#include "ExternHeader.hpp"
int e = 0;
```

ConstexprHeader.hpp

```
int constexpr c = 0; // Must be defined in header since constexpr must be initialized.
```

Include1.hpp

```
void print1();
```

Include1.cpp

```
#include "Include1.hpp"
#include "ExternHeader.hpp"
#include "ConstexprHeader.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void print1() {
    std::cout << "1: extern = " << &e << ", constexpr = " << &c << "\n";
}
```

Include2.hpp

```
void print2();
```

Include2.cpp

```
#include "Include2.hpp"
#include "ExternHeader.hpp"
#include "ConstexprHeader.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void print2() {
    std::cout << "2: extern = " << &e << ", constexpr = " << &c << "\n";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Include1.hpp"
#include "Include2.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    print1();
    print2();
    return 0;
}
```

Which prints:

```
1: extern = 0x1000020a8, constexpr = 0x100001ed0
2: extern = 0x1000020a8, constexpr = 0x100001ed4
```

IE the `constexpr` is allocated twice whereas the `extern` is allocated once.
This is counterintuitive to me, since I 'expect' `constexpr` to be more optimized than `extern`.

Edit: `const` and `constexpr` have the same behaviour, with regard to allocation, therefore from that point of view the behaviour is as expected. Though, as I said, I was surprised when I came across the behaviour of `constexpr`.

Comment: It's an optimization thing - the `constexpr` is placed at local scope (whenever needed) to have fast access, `extern` is placed in the global data segment to allow reads/writes to the same variable (it's probbaly done through a pointer)

Comment: @Xeverous `constexpr` doesn't relocate variables into a different scope. You're probably thinking of constant folding, which is a compiler optimization that *might* be performed. We see two addresses for `constexpr` not because it's put into some local scope, but because `const` objects have internal linkage, so every source file has its own copy. `inline constexpr` fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it **somewhat** is...

```
//===================================================================
// afile.h

#ifndef AFILE
#define AFILE

#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

enum class IDs {

  id1,
  id2,
  id3,
  END

};

// This is the extern declaration of a **constexpr**, use simply **const**
extern const int ids[std::size_t(IDs::END)];

// These functions will demonstrate its usage

template<int id> void Foo() { std::cout << "I am " << id << std::endl; }

extern void Bar();

#endif // AFILE

//===================================================================
// afile.cpp

#include "afile.h"

// Here we define the consexpr. 
// It is **constexpr** in this unit and **const** in all other units
constexpr int ids[std::size_t(IDs::END)] = {

  int(IDs::id1),
  int(IDs::id2),
  int(IDs::id3)

};

// The Bar function demonstrates that ids is really constexpr
void Bar() {

  Foo<ids[0]      >();
  Foo<ids[1] + 123>();
  Foo<ids[2] / 2  >();

}

//===================================================================
// bfile.h

#ifndef BFILE
#define BFILE

// These functions will demonstrate usage of constexpr ids in an extern unit

extern void Baz();
extern void Qux();


#endif // BFILE

//===================================================================
// bfile.cpp

#include "afile.h"

// Baz demonstrates that ids is (or works as) an extern field
void Baz() {

  for (int i: ids) std::cout << i << ", ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

}

// Qux demonstrates that extern ids cannot work as constexpr, though
void Qux() {

#if 0 // changing me to non-0 gives you a compile-time error...

  Foo<ids[0]>();

#endif

  std::cout << "Qux: 'I don't see ids as consexpr, indeed.'" 
            << std::endl;

}

//===================================================================
// main.cpp

#include "afile.h"
#include "bfile.h"

int main(int , char **)
{

  Bar();
  Baz();
  Qux();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I successfully used the trick `extern const` + `constexpr` to allocate a complex structure in `.text` segment for an embedded project with GCC 5.4.1.

Comment: Is it even legal?