# error: constexpr variable 'struct2Var' must be initialized by a constant expression

Tags: c++, compilation, clang

The following program is failing when compiling with Clang with **error: constexpr variable 'struct2Var' must be initialized by a constant expression {var, 2100433}**
.

If I remove `__attribute__((weak))`  from "var" declaration, it is passing without any issues.

Can somebody please explain the theory/reason behind this error.

```
struct myStruct
{
public:
 constexpr operator const wchar_t*() const
 {
  return &m_cch;
 }

 const wchar_t m_cch;
};

extern  __attribute__((weak)) const constexpr myStruct var {'a'};

struct myStruct2
{
 const wchar_t* stzKey = nullptr;

 int intvar = 0;
};

static constexpr const myStruct2 struct2Var[1]
{
  {var, 2100433}
};
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/352944650a980358

Comment: Here is the repro: https://godbolt.org/z/b3W9ka

Comment: You should [edit] your question to point the fact that gcc & clang have a different behaviour. This is an _important_ detail.

Comment: Simplified version: https://godbolt.org/z/cXtY9z

Answer (score 3):

It looks like using `__attribute__((weak))` discards the `constexpr` qualifier with clang but not with gcc. Despite clang trying to be a drop in replacement for gcc, it might implement such non standard feature differently. In that case, I would say that neither gcc nor clang is wrong.

Also, global `constexpr` might be tricky to maintain as they should all be defined consistently in every translation unit. To face this issue, [inline variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896773/11350445) have been added to c++17.

Comment: It seems you are right. I may need to get it confirmed. Thanks Meatboy for great information.