# Are there any variables whose address can not be obtained?

Tags: c++

I am learning for my CPP exam and one of the questions will be like this: "How to get variable address and are there any variables whose address cannot be obtained"?

So first one is easy, you just use "&" operator, but are there any variables (mind you that question only concerns variables!) whose address cannot be accessed with ampersand?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: References and rvalues come to mind. I don't know if you would consider those "variables".

Comment: No, every variable's address can be obtained.

Comment: Well, you can't obtain the address of a bit. The smallest thing you can address in C++ is a byte.

Comment: _"...variables..."_ such an ill defined term, see __Built-in address-of operator__ in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access  This being an exam question depends on how your course has defined __variable__.

Comment: Those which are of type with `operator&` overloaded in such a way, from which you can not get to the address? You'd have to use `std::addressof`.

Comment: @Carl `std::bitset` provides a nice _workaround_ though.

Comment: If you consider a preprocessor macro such as `#define MAX_DUMBNESS 255` a variable, you can't get the address of that.  (I personally don't)

Comment: @carl post this as answer with a demo and I'll upvote :-)

Comment: @zzxyz I don't think anyone does.

Comment: @zzxyz A macro is not even remotely related to a _variable_.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why wouldn't a bit field be considered a variable? You can read from it and assign to it just like any other variable.

Comment: @Barmar I hadn't thought of bit fields. Retracted.

Comment: I do not get the downvotes, it does not seem to be that obvious.

Comment: @DerekJohnson The whole point of exercises like this is for you to try to figure it out yourself. That's how you understand the underlying concepts.

Comment: @Christophe Done!

Comment: I bet this question means obsolete `register` variable

Comment: If you count reference you cannot get the address of the actual reference, only what it refers to.

Comment: What about the address of a `constexpr` `int`?  I would think some answers should address the possibility, or impossibility, of finding a way to create a 'variable' that is a prvalue - perhaps a contradiction in terms, but worth commenting on, I think.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14872240/368896 for discussion of attempt to take address of a (non-static-member) `constexpr`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> are there any variables whose address cannot be obtained?

You cannot get addresses of member variables of structs that are bit-fields.

From [the C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.bit#3):

> The address-of operator & shall not be applied to a bit-field, so there are no pointers to bit-fields.

Answer (score 5):

> but are there any variables (mind you that question only concerns variables!) whose address cannot be accessed with ampersand?

I think the question in your content is different from the one from the title. I assume the one in your content is what you want.

There are variables whose address can't be obtained by ampersand, because you can overload that operator.

The code below, `&a` won't give you the address of `a`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    int operator &() {
        return 900;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo a;
    std::cout << (&a) << "\n";
}
```

NOTE: Such variable's address can be obtained by other methods. Basically the principle is erasing the type so that the overloaded operator has no effect. `std::addressof` implemented this functionality.

Comment: [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) gets around this.

Comment: This answer is technically right, because the question asks specifically about `operator&` *("whose address cannot be accessed with ampersand?")*. But you can use [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) in that case.

Comment: @NathanOliver Note in OP's description in the **content**, it's "**cannot be accessed with ampersand**".

Answer (score 3):

So as an example. The smallest thing you can address in C++ is a byte, and so attempting to access for example any of the 1 bit `uint8_t`'s inside this `bitField` is not legal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

struct bitField {
    uint8_t n0 : 1;
    uint8_t n1 : 1;
    uint8_t n2 : 1;
    uint8_t n3 : 1;
    uint8_t n4 : 1;
    uint8_t n5 : 1;
    uint8_t n6 : 1;
    uint8_t n7 : 1;
};

int main() {
    bitField example;

    // Can address the whole struct
    std::cout << &example << '\n'; // FINE, addresses a byte

    // Can not address for example n4 directly
    std::cout << &example.n4; // ERROR, Can not address a bit

    // Printing it's value is fine though
    std::cout << example.n4 << '\n'; // FINE, not getting address

    return 0;
}
```

As TheDude mentioned in the comment section however, the STL has a class `std::bitset<N>` which offers a *workaround* for this. It basically wraps an array of bools. Still, the end result is indexing bytes, not bits.

Comment: @user4581301 Updated